# cannot read property of upoladed file through nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have been trying to upload a file smoothly without hitches through the NodeJS tutorials at tutorialspoint.com. The files get uploaded into the folder meant to hold the uploaded files but instead of its original name, the file is renamed to some other value like a hash value or timestamp. The error I get is shown below.

It would also be great if someone can tell me how the file gets uploaded, so that I can better understand any error I have made.

Here is the detail of the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/server_upload.js:18:26
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NodeJS_Tutorialspoint/Tutorial7_Express/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:52:37)
at Immediate.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:440:18)
```

The programs for the file upload process:

index_upload.html :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File Uploading Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>File Upload:</h3>
    Select a file to upload: <br />
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="filename" size="50" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

server_upload.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({ dest: 'Uploads/'}).single('filename'));

app.get('/index_upload.html', function (req, res) 
{
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index_upload.html" );
})

app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) 
{
    console.log(req.files.file.name);
    console.log(req.files.file.path);
    console.log(req.files.file.type);
    var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;
    fs.readFile( req.files.file.path, function (err, data) 
    {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) 
        {
            if( err )
            {
                console.log( err );
            }
            else
            {
                response = 
                {
                    message:'File uploaded successfully',
                    filename:req.files.file.name
                };
            }
            console.log( response );
            res.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );
        });
    });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () 
{
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port) 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing Name = "filename" on HTML

```
console.log(req.files.filename.name);
console.log(req.files.filename.path);
console.log(req.files.filename.type);
```

Comment: oh, seems like I've made a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. Appreciate it